How do I avoid unnecessary renders if I update state before calling React Query?
I have a question I want advice on.  I'm using react query and what I want is my app to render as soon as the query is called and then once it’s complete.
However, if I have a state called "date".  When I update date, it re-renders unnecessarily. When I use a useRef in the react query dependency array, it doesnt get triggered.  Only gets triggered if its a usestate.  Whats the best way to accomplish this?
This triggers multiple renders BUT api is called accordingly:
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");
    const {
        data,
        isLoading
    } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["chat", date],
        queryFn: () => getChat(date),
    });

This does not trigger API when date is changed, but I would assume changing date would not trigger a rerender:
    const date = useRef("");
    const {
        data,
        isLoading
    } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["chat", date.current],
        queryFn: () => getChat(date.current),
    });


Stop counting renders and discuss what problem you’re experiencing - e.g. stale date, no loader when there should be a loader, etc. Your first code snippet looks to be exactly how you should be using react query, so what’s the real problem? If you have some data that a fetch function needs to query an API, it should absolutely be state. Your question is too zoomed in on implementation details that you won’t get a satisfactory answer and it’s bordering on an XY problem

So great point.  I’ve been so fixated on reducing renders that this may not be an issue. So is it fair to say multiple renders are okay if it has no consequences?  I was always under the impression that renders should only happen if the screen needs to change.

The renders are a mere implementation detail of the framework you chose. You only should be focused on them if you are experiencing logical problems, or performance problems. Side note: if you're not sure if you're experiencing a performance problem, you aren't - you'll 100% know it when you see it. If you aren't experiencing logical problems (e.g. flashing, "wrong" data being displayed, etc) ignore renders and just keep building.
